# Compare two different array of objects and return boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays

I pursuing my 12th grade, trying hard to learn react and javascript, I am doing some basic exercise like comparing array of objects and returning true or false if the id matches, I found some workable solutions for the same but all are returning me back the difference of that two array objects I need to see boolean (true) if value matches else false. I am struggling to get this  I am confused with the retzurn type of the filter and some methods in array. Could anyone help me out to achieve this output? Thanks in advance!

```js
const a = [
  { id: '1234', description: 'PrdOne', version: '3', categories: '--' },
  { id: '12345', description: 'PrdTwo', version: '2', categories: '--' },
  { id: '123456', description: 'PrdThree', version: '2', categories: '--' },
];

const b = [
  { id: '1234', description: 'PrdOne', version: '3', categories: '--' },
  { id: '12345', description: 'PrdTwo', version: '2', categories: '--' },
];

let result = a.filter(o => !b.some(v => v.id === o.id));

console.log(result);
```

It's giving me the difference but I need boolean value (true) if there is a match else false

Comment: just replace `filter` with `some`

Comment: @pilchard  you mean a.some(0 => !b.some()) if yes, will it check against all the items in both array of objs?

Comment: if you just want to know if there is a match then you don't need to check all, just until there is a match, so yes `a.some(0 => !b.some());` (`some()` stops short on first true match). If you want to know *how many* matches then keep your `filter` and check the length. `a.filter(o => !b.some(v => v.id === o.id)).length;` or `a.filter(o => !b.some(v => v.id === o.id)).length > 0` for a boolean.

Comment: @pilchard mmm, I am planning to add different items which will contain different ID I need to check each element in both array of objects and I need to return false or true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method filter will remove items inside your array 'a' each time the condition inside the filter will return false. If the method inside your filter method return true, it will pass over the iteration.

So what you need is to use some() method instead of filter, like this :

```
let result = a.some(o => !b.some(v => v.id === o.id));
```

If you want to know the return of your condition of each item of your array, just replace some() method by map() :

```
let result = a.map(o => !b.some(v => v.id === o.id));
```

This will replace each item of a by the return of the matching condition.

Comment: I am planning to check each and every element in both array of objects, and I need to return the true or false, so that I can verify the length of the items which has same ID later.

Comment: In this case, you can use .map() instead of some(), it will return true or false for each item of your array 'a'